# How to check the link is enabled in Webdriver using java?

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have searched the forums before posting this issue here. I have found some answers but i am not able to get the success from the answers in that. My issue is

How to check the link is enabled in Webdriver using java. Please find the attached screen shots for the same.

[image]

[image]

I have written the code for this:

```
WebElement textlink = driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("lnkView_ID")));
if (textlink.isEnabled())
   System.out.println("View link: Enabled");
else
   System.out.println("View link: Disabled");
```

Please help me out with this issue. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the error reported?

Comment: Also, what is the actual locator you are using for locating the link? Can you mention that too?

Comment: I'd recommend double-checking that ID you're using. Is it definitely unique and constant; it doesn't change each time you load the page, or refresh the list of actions does it? Also, have you definitely got it preset in your script? Apart from that, your code looks like it's trying to do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not getting any error but its printing Enabled message even it is disabled. I am using the ID property for locating the link. id = ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_grdAppln_ctl02_lnkView

Comment: In the ID property, on the number ctl02 will change when the new row is added. but i want it for the same row with ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_grdAppln_ctl02_lnkView. Because, i will create new Applicant every time for different users when i run it. So the id property will be the same for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
String isDisabled = textlink.getAttribute("disabled");
if (isDisabled==null || !isDisabled.equals("disabled")){
   System.out.println("View link: Enabled");
}else{
   System.out.println("View link: Disabled");
}
```

It looks like the attribute "disabled" is the toggle for whether it is enabled or not, so you can check for it using `getAttribute();`

Answer (score 0):

Check for the attribute disabled in  tag. As 'View' link is disabled and you can find from your HTML that its represented by disabled="disabled". Write an identifier in XPath for  or use Id identifier and like below find the link status using the attribute value for disabled.

```
string viewLinkXpath = "//tobody/tr/td/a";
IWebElement viewLinkElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(viewLinkXpath));
if(viewLinkElement.GetAttribute("disabled")!="disabled")
{
   Console.WriteLine("View link enabled");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide attribute name as input for `getAttribute` instead of providing attribute value. For example:

```
WebElement test=d.findElement(By.xpath(ORNsk.prevXpath));
String isDisabled=test.getAttribute("class");
```

Here `class` is attribute name.