# how can i check if a checkbox is enabled (doesn't matter checked or unchecked.)

Tags: selenium, checkbox

I am new to selenium, I am trying to verify if a checkbox is enabled on a page.It does not matter if it is checked or unchecked. I only have to verify that it can be selected i.e it is enabled for usage.
I have the id of the checkbox that is "chkEP". Kindly help. I am using java.

I have found different answers against my query via googling it but they all are verifying if chechbox is checked or not. Many many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebElement interface has an `isEnabled` method on it. See [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html).

Otherwise, you can manually check the attribute - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104259/how-to-check-the-link-is-enabled-in-webdriver-using-java). Code:

```
String isDisabled = textlink.getAttribute("disabled");
if (isDisabled==null || !isDisabled.equals("disabled")){
   System.out.println("View link: Enabled");
}else{
   System.out.println("View link: Disabled");
}
```

Comment: it is dispaying "textlink can not be resolved". Am i missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you will need to change textlink to the name of your checkbox Element. Could you now just do yourCheckBoxElement.isEnabled?

Comment: @newLearner. You need to first select the element: driver.FindElement(By.<oneoftheoptions>). Where <oneoftheoptions> is one of the supported ways of finding the element, e.g. By.id(). Then you should just be able to use isEnabled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried isEnabled()??

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
we.isEnabled();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use the webdriver isEnabled() method.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("value"));
if (element.isEnabled()) {
    //insert your code here
}
```

Please note that if the element is not present in the web page, noSuchElementException will be thrown in the first line itself.